# strange behavior with boost::bind in virtual member function

Tags: c++, boost, bind

i have two classes, one has virtual function

```
class OKClass 
{  
public:  
    void PrintTest() {  
        std::cout << "print from OK class " << std::endl;  
    }  
}; 

class CrashClass 
{  
public:  
    virtual void PrintTest() {  
        std::cout << "print from virtual Crash class " << std::endl;  
    }  
};
```

I put the two classes in the following test code
the CrashClass crashes when call func()
the OkClass print the word "print from OK class ", which should not. since the shared_ptr test was released when out of scope. 
can any explain to me why this strange thing happen??

thank you

```
boost::function0<void> func;
{
    boost::shared_ptr<CrashClass> test(new CrashClass);
    func = boost::bind(&CrashClass::PrintTest, boost::bind(&CrashClass::wptr::lock, CrashClass::wptr(test)));
}
func();
```

---

sry for short of information

```
typedef boost::weaked_ptr<CrashClass> wptr
```

i have know the reason why the first class works, and the second crashed

and i have using a Functor to work around this problem

thanks anyway

Comment: You need to paste in much more code than you have; what's `wptr`, for example?

Comment: I do not know what your wptr stuff is, as the code is missing (as Chris Jester-Young has pointed out).  However, I can tell you that you are binding a function object to the first argument of PrintTest, but PrintTest is member method and should have the first argument bound to an instance of the class.  If wptr::lock is a function that returns the instance, then you will need more work to get this to work, but at that point, it is just guessing and not really an answer.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts. You can now edit your question again and leave comments under answers that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what wptr is, I can only guess that when test goes out of scope, the instance of CrashClass is being deleted.  If this is the case, you should be able to remove the braces to prevent the crash.  Though "delay" is probably more accurate than "prevent."

Answer (score 0):

`boost::weak_ptr` does not *guarantee* that the memory it points to will stick around. That's pretty much the entire point of the class. It is the responsibility of the holder of the `weak_ptr` to lock it (getting a `shared_ptr`) and *test* that pointer before calling it. Otherwise, you're using `weak_ptr` wrong.